# How do I update metadata on songs already synced to my device?

Tags: zune, music

I want to re-tag a bunch of songs to organize my music on my phone.

For example cleaning up genres: putting Hip hop, Hip-hop, Hiphop, Hip-hop/Rap, Gansta Rap, etc., all in a single genre.

I've done this in Zune but the changes aren't showing on my device after syncing.

Comment: Have you tried removing the songs from your phone and syncing them again?

Comment: I was hoping that would be a last resort, since I would have to make a list of all the songs on my device first.

Comment: You can create a playlist of all songs currently on your device, sync the playlist to Zune, remove all the songs from the device, then re-sync the playlist you created.  As long as the file names are unchanged, it should sync back properly.

Comment: @cowgod took a few hours to sync over WiFi, but that went well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that meta-tags on my phone are now syncing automatically as changes are made in Zune.

The determining factor seems to be if the device is syncing over WiFi or USB.

**When plugged in to a USB port the meta-tags will sync.**

Answer (score 2):

Meta-tag by itself will not be synced. You'll have to remove the files from the device, and re-sync.

If updating a large number of songs, one method could be to save a playlist of all the songs to Zune. After erasing them from the device, copy them back from the playlist.